# Question about constructing complex entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

How to construct an entire function for infinitely many prescribed values?

i.e. I hope to find an entire function $f$ given $f(z_k) = w_k$ ($w_k$ might not be zero) for a sequence of $\{z_k\}$ with no finite accumulation points.

Can anyone give me some idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to combine Mittag-Leffler's theorem with the Weierstrass factorization theorem.  Weierstrass gives you an entire function
$g(z)$ which has a simple zero at each $z_k$.  Mittag-Leffler gives you a meromorphic function $h(z)$ with a simple pole at each $z_k$ where $w_k \ne 0$, and residue $w_k/g'(z_k)$ there.  After removing the removable singularities at each 
$z_k$,  $f(z) = g(z) h(z)$ is the desired function.