# Applying Liouville's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f : \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ be an entire function such that $2f(1) = f(0)$. What can you say about $f$?

Question is asked under Liouville's theorem, so it must be some direct application of it, but I can't think of a suitable way

I can think of one such entire function, namely $f(z) = 2-z$ and multiples of it.

Comment: $(z^2-z)g(z)$ will do this for any entire $g.$

Comment: Or $$f(z) = \left(z + \frac{2 g(1)}{g(0)-2g(1)}\right) g(z)$$ for any entire $g$ with $2 g(1) \ne g(0)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't say much.  There are lots of such functions.  In fact, you can specify arbitrarily the values of $f$ at any sequence of points of $\mathbb C$ with no finite limit point, and there will be an entire function with those values at those points.

Comment: Hmm, I presume this is consequence of identity/uniqueness theorem. I guess some information was missing in the question.

Comment: It is a consequence of Mittag-Leffler's theorem and the Weierstrass factorization theorem.  See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909354/question-about-constructing-complex-entire-function).